# Pause and Continue a Runnable object?

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a runnable in my code, and I have to start it by pressing a button in my app, and stop it by pressing an another button.

The problem occurs when I press the stop button. It stops the runnable, but I can't start it again, when I press the start button.

My code:

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_TimerStart:
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Clicked");
        r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mService != null) {
                    if(running) {
                        str2 = Ef.getText().toString();
                        str2 = str2.substring(0, 0) + "E" + str2.substring(0, str2.length());
                        mService.sendAlert(mDevice, str2);
                        v.postDelayed(r, 6 * 1000);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        v.post(r);
        break;
    case R.id.button_TimerStop:
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Clicked");
        if(running = true) {
            running = false;
        }
    default:
        Log.e(TAG,"wrong Click event");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a new one everytime the start button is pressed.

Comment: You're never setting running to true once it's false.

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong never fix OP's code when editing a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `running` flag to signify that you want to stop it.

Instead use removeCallbacks() to remove the Runnables from the the list to get played.

```
/to stop the runnable:
v.removeCallbacks(r);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(running = true)
```

Should be

```
if(running == true)
```

Additionally, you need to set `running = true` when you press the Start button.

Comment: This will solve the logic error, but if the runnable is not going to do anything then there is no reason to keep it firing. removeCallbacks() is a better way to stop it IMO because that will actually prevent it from firing rather then set a flag to tell it to do nothing when it does fire.

Comment: I agree, and I've upvoted your answer. I was just pointing out the obvious mistakes. :)